# MapBox Navigation frameworks not installing correctly via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox

I am trying to install the MapBox Navigation SDK to my Xcode project, but I keep running into a problem. I previously installed the generic MapBox SDK via cocoapods without issue, but when adding the Navigation SDK to my podfile and updating, many of the frameworks installed are appearing as red (implying the actually framework wasn't installed I suppose?). Some of the frameworks installed correctly (MapBox, MapBoxDirections), but most are presenting this issue. If anybody sees something out of sorts with my podfile or know some sort of solution to this issue, please let me know.

[image: My podfile]
My Podfile

[image: My project file]
My project file

[image: How the frameworks are appearing in my project.]
How the frameworks are appearing in my project.

Comment: did you check the MapBox pod versions for your Swift version?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this (this is my first project utilizing cocoapods). Essentially what I've done is initialized the podfile, pasted the suggested text into the podfile, ran pod update in my terminal, and all of these frameworks were installed but don't seem to path to the correct location. I.e. I must not have the actual frameworks downloaded? @emrahkorkmaz

Comment: just curious, why just append MapBox-Navigation into podfile, searching out some projects and all of them have installed with `mapbox-sdk`

Comment: MapBox-Navigation installs the same frameworks that Mapbox-sdk does if I'm not mistaken (and then some additional ones). I've tried installing both pods and the problem persists.

Comment: I've just tried to get the pod, but I guess MapBox SDK is quite big then I got `OpenSSL` error . Did you update the pod before the install it with `pod repo update`

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Were you struggling to get the SDK to work as well? @emrahkorkmaz

Comment: yeah actually, I'vent installed it completely, it was weird.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem happen only with objective c language . **when you we through the swift with above version Xcode 9 .its ok work fine to install the pod.**

Answer (score 0):

I had mail to mapbox regarding the issues, they replay me and suggest me try with carthage . I try it through the **carthage** we have no issues so please go with **carthage**.